# php class variables

Tags: php, class, session, variables

I have a class named MyCart.

```
Class MyCartClass
{
var $MyCart;  

function getCart(){
  return $this->MyCart;
}

function addItem($item){

    if ($this->MyCart){
        $this->MyCart .= ','.$item;
    } 
    else{
        $this->MyCart = $item;
    }

}

};

$globalCart = new MyCartClass; // create an instance of the class
```

The variable `"$MyCart"` is a string containing all the items in the cart, separated with a comma.

Now, I save this class to a file named `"cart.php"` and I include it in another file.

HOWEVER, every time I call the function `"addItem"`, the if statement goes to the else branch, which means that the `"$MyCart"` variable does not contain the current state of the cart.

Do i need to store the state of my cart into a "session" variable? 
Cause this way it will be accessible from all files for sure..

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code, provided you are calling it within the same program run (HTTP call, or whatever). *Nothing* will persist between HTTP calls unless you use a session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean saving it between request then yes you need to put it in $_SESSION.

Otherwise within one request you can use your `$globalCart` and not lose the contents of your `$myCart` var.

Comment: Thank you "yes123". It seems that there is no other way than storing it into $_SESSION I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a string to store a list.  It's just a bad idea all around.

Instead, store `$items` as an array, and define it in the constructor

```
class Cart {

    function __construct() {
        $this->items = array();
    }

    function add($item) {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    function save() {
        $SESSION["cart"] = $this->items;
    }

    function get_items_string() {
        return join(",", $this->items);
    }

}
```

My PHP is a little rusty, but that should get you started.

Comment: the question wasnt' about how to properly store it.

Comment: Thank you. So, by storing the result of the "add new item" function into this array is not enough to hold this result in the entire site, right? I definitely need a session. Is that correct. Thank all of you guys for the immediate response!

Comment: Yup, definitely use a session, and yes, I know the question wasn't about how to store it, but I thought the OP had the false impression that sessions can only store strings, which isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this just store the data in an array and use serialize and deserialize to store the data:

```
Class MyCartClass { 
    var $MyCart = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->MyCart = deserialize($_SESSION['CART']);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $_SESSION['CART'] = serialize($this->MyCart);
    }


    function getCart(){
        return $this->MyCart;
    }

    function addItem($item){
        $this->MyCart[] = $item;   
    }
}
```

Please note I just wrote this quickly and didn't run it as I don't have access to run it right now.  :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't need to serialise session data.

Answer (score 0):

your can even serialise all class to $_SESSION[] ... but generally good idea is to store in session some id - as example user id & store all all other data in mysql. Getting it each time, is needed ...